# Non Commutative Bernstein Inequality

Tags: probability, distribution-tails

In the proof for noncommutative Bernstein Inequality, a symbol is used whose intuition is not clear.

In the picture, Pr[X symbol A] is used. What is the semantic meaning of that symbol.[image]

Can someone explain the first line of proof of operator Markov inequality given in this picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties):

> For arbitrary square matrices $M, N$ we write $M\succeq N$ if $M - N \succeq 0$; i.e., $M - N$ is positive semi-definite. This defines a partial ordering on the set of all square matrices. One can similarly define a strict partial ordering $M \succ N$.

Your symbol is the negation of this. I.e., $M\not\succeq N$ if $M - N$ is **not** positive semi-definite.

---

Regarding the first sentence of the proof. $X \not\preceq  A$ is equivalent to $A-X$ not positive semi-definite, and therefore equivalent to $A^{-1/2}(A-X)A^{1/2} = I-A^{-1/2}X A^{1/2}$ not positive semi-definite. I.e., with the notations, $A^{-1/2}X A^{1/2} \not\preceq I$. What does that mean? It means the at least one of the eigenvalues of $I-A^{-1/2}X A^{1/2}$ is negative, or (again, equivalently) that at least one of the eigenvalues of $A^{-1/2}X A^{1/2}$ is $> 1$. This is precisely saying $\lVert A^{-1/2}X A^{1/2}\rVert > 1$. (The spectral norm being the (absolute value of the) maximum eigenvalue.)

Comment: Okay. I get this part. Can you explain the first line of proof for Markov Inequality in the picture.

Comment: What in particular? The first sentence? (Also, it'd be better if you didn't change the question too often -- just for information.)

Comment: In particular the first line, where they proof that spectral norm is greater than 1. I didn't get that part.

Comment: @GouravKumar See my edit.

Comment: I have difficulty in understanding the proof of non Commutative Bernstein Inequality. Can you help with that?

Comment: @GouravKumar You may want to post that as a new, separate question. (I'll help if I can, but it's getting late here.)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2530260/noncommutative-bernstine-inequality-proof Here is the link to that question. It shouldn't take much time for you I guess.